# Switchover delay in my UPS circuit

Tags: relay, delay, ups

I previously posted a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617320/can-anyone-help-me-with-this-delay-problem-in-my-ups-circuit) regarding my circuit. I was having a delay in my circuit releasing the relay when the power was down. Some people suggested to try out some stuff and I did that but, I was still having the problem.

This was my first version
[image]
Here I used a 24 V relay directly connected to the power line believing that when the power goes down the relay will release and start supplying from the battery. But it had a significant delay of about 1-2 s. After that someone recommended to remove the relay and connect the boost converter directly and lower the output voltage little bit that is, right below the adapter output voltage so that even though the boost converter is connected directly it won’t use the battery power because the output voltage of the adapter is high hence no boosting occurs. I tried that but it didn’t work some how the laptop was sucking 500 mAh from the battery and about 200 mAh from the adapter. The circuit is below..
[image]

Then upon further testing I realised that it was my adapters fault. When the power goes down, the output of the adapter doesn’t drops instantly and since relays have a min release voltage, so until the output voltage goes below that release voltage the relay stays engaged hence the delay. So I came up with the circuit that consists of a BC547 transistor paired with potentiometer that lets me set the voltage at which the transistor cuts the power from the relay turning it off. This way I am basically bypassing the relays min release voltage. And it worked sort of but still my laptop turns off when there is a power outage. But now the relay clicks right after I cut the mains supply. Maybe a few milliseconds of delay or I don’t know what is the problem. This is the circuit I came up with:
[image]

I also added two 4700 uF caps but it didn’t work.

This is the [boost converter](https://quartzcomponents.com/products/150w-dc-dc-step-up-boost-converter-10-32v-to-12-35v-6a-adjustable-power-supply-module?variant=37988484546744&currency=INR&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&utm_campaign=gs-2020-12-29&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=Cj0KCQjwsdiTBhD5ARIsAIpW8CJF0OlnNOYvnhTMYlJt39N5NUUTvH5ILQ1vrWxHyHUmNPDQ7Phx-acaApUXEALw_wcB) I used.
Use this kind of [potentiometer](https://quartzcomponents.com/products/10k-ohm-preset-potentiometer?variant=31898022445191&currency=INR&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&utm_campaign=gs-2020-12-29&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=Cj0KCQjwsdiTBhD5ARIsAIpW8CIo9SuSH9pIuaBxLBzbJ3nfH32PDXOsRyzA3wI-FmT168tVltMO_MEaAhkkEALw_wcB).

Please help me and give some of your big brain stuff  I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: You ask for help, but with what exactly? There is no question found to answer.

Comment: Can you include voltage range , current limits and power rating of each source and load?  U stands for uninterruptible, yet the concept is not shown in any diagram to be viable.  Transient inrush loads on a boost converter could be a problem and exceed the 24V source ability. The solution may not be work without specs and a lot of work.

Comment: Your mAh figures, are they actually current by any chance (mA)?

Comment: Sorry, your question (or lack thereof since not a single question mark) is unclear. Can you make a truth table of what you want from the circuit and another with what it actually does? Or boil it down to a specific question?

Comment: This wouldn't make it stick for seconds, but one possible problem is that you're just using a single diode as a snubber for your relay. That will make the relay turn off slowly; it'll turn off faster if you add a resistor or zener diode in series with the catch diode (cathode to cathode if you use a zener).

Comment: The usual way for maintaining power during switch-over (and this is certainly needed for critical care equipment in hospitals, for example) is to use double conversion systems. They exist. And they work.

Comment: I am sorry for not providing the correct information… my bad.. so my laptop pulls around 1 amp fully loaded with tasks …and what I want is to solve this delay problem … so if anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here or even provide a proper circuit that will be helpful

Comment: Also my laptops minimum working voltage is around 18.2v

Comment: can you test your laptop with 14.4V DC +/- 2.4 V  A simpler solution will then exist.. or use 5S3P battery Specs belong in a concise list in the question

Comment: My laptop turns off at 18 v….. I measured it

Comment: So can you make a 6S 2P pack with same number of batteries and eliminate the boost converter?

Comment: I mean for the 5s the lowest voltage would be 15 volts considering the cutoff voltage is 3 volts on the bms ... And for 6s the highest would be 25 volts.... And that would be crossing the safe limits ... Thats why i used a boost converter to boost the 4s3p pack ..... In the beginning i decided to use a 6s pack .... But then realised if i do that i won't be able to charge the battery via the laptop charger .... Kinda defeats the purpose of a ups (if i have to buy a separate charger).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry the first try didn't work.

You should be aware that your approach is not much used for smallish systems. The basic problem is that, since you are starting to act when Vcc has actually dropped, you are playing catch-up, and that's not a good approach.

The more standard approach looks like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWSoYk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The key here is to use Vcc greater than the battery voltage. The battery is constantly being trickle charged, and is protected by D2, which may be an implicit part of the charger.

So, as long as Vcc is present, the D1/D3 pair makes sure that it provides power. When Vcc drops, and the battery voltage is greater, the battery drives the buck converter. The buck converter sees a change in input voltage when Vcc drops, but stays within range. There is no crossover transient to deal with.

You would obviously add circuitry to indicate things like loss of AC and low battery, but that is up to you.

Comment: But I am using a boost converter

Comment: Also the charger am using runs on dc to charge a lithium ion pack….

Comment: @Dvlogs Which isn’t working out for you, hence WhatRoughBeast suggested a different solution. Just connect your charger on the DC output of your power supply. Depending on your DC input, battery and output voltage, you could use a boost if that fits better.

Comment: Battery voltage is below the output voltage, according to the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely making it harder than it is.  The DPDT switch appears to have no good purpose.

I gather you don't want the boost converter running while able to use AC power, so...

I would re-wire it so the charger is charging the battery at all times.  Thus eliminating the switch altogether.   You connect the battery to the boost converter when AC power fails.

Trying to use the laptop power supply to operate the relay is giving you too slow a transition,  Iwould use a separate power supply in "wall wart" form factor that cuts power instantly when AC power is lost.  An AC one with an actual transformer would be a sure bet.

You realize most laptops have a built-in UPS, right? It's called "their internal battery".   Maybe hit up iFixit and get a replacement battery for it.

Comment: Not possible where I live ..... But hey i think I understand this now ... I will remove the circuit the add a Diode in series with the power supply and the battery and both of them connected with the boost converter... I think the diodes will do the trick...

Comment: And the there is a reason why i used dpdt switch... So the charger am using keeps an led on ... While the battery is not charging ... Simply put as soon as I connect the battery it turns the led on.... (When am not even supplying it power)